# application crashes while scrolling long list selector

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I am using a longlistselector control in my WP7 app, to show some products, the problem is that when i scroll to the last few items at the bottom , the application crashes .
Any idea why it is happening?[image]

Comment: Are you running the application on the Mango emulator? I've seen an issue where some scrolling scenarios cause the application to exit (without exception) on the beta emulator.

Comment: I have attached an image of the exception object, this code "Application_UnhandledException" is in app.xaml.cs file.

Answer (score 1):

This is because longlistselecter was used inside a scrollviewer , i removed the scrollviewer and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, although it wasn't in a ScrollViewer, it was in a Grid.  Removing it from the Grid resolved the issue.